# How can I extract certain data from a site using php?

Tags: php, json, extract

I'm creating a loading screen for a game and when a user connects I want certain variables to be automatically obtained. While searching the internet, I've seen people suggest using preg_match, but that doesn't seem to work for me.

This is what I tried to use, but It's probably not setup right.

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://runtime.fivem.net/api/servers/');

preg_match('mapname', $content, $match);
$mapname = $match[1];
```

Is there any other function that I could use or how could I utilize this function correctly? Any tips and examples would help greatly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you use returns data in json format. You can use the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to parse it and get the data you need. The example below prints the number of clients from the first element in the list.

```
$json = json_decode($content);
echo $json[0]->Data->clients;
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured I was missing something.